# Can you implement factorial using a macro in C?

Tags: c, macros

I am searching for an example of computing a factorial using a macro. I am not finding anything that works. Is there a specific reason there isn't one? Is this because of C's implementation?

I understand that you cannot have recursion in a macro, but there is a way to have an iterative factorial function. Why isn't it possible in C, to have a factorial macro?

For reference here is an example that I have found of an iterative implementation of the factorial function:

```
int factorial(int N) {
    int product = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= N; j++)
        product *= j;
    return product;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a macro rather than a function?

Comment: Where? In **N**, **Z**, **R**, or **C**?

Comment: I'm wanting to get a better understanding on the language itself

Comment: @deamentiaemundi in N is fine

Comment: A macro cannot be expanded recursively, per the preprocessor's specification in the Standard.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist What about an iterative version of the function?

Comment: What is a factorial macro?

Comment: @immibis a macro that calculates the factorial of a number.

Comment: Can't do that either. The preprocessor is not Turing-complete: It is in general capable of defining/undefining macros, expanding them, testing for their presence, comparing their integer value, substituting, appending or prepending text, but has little to no control flow. It can't loop back; it runs in one pass forward through the source file.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist so C cannot have any type of loop in a macro then?

Comment: 20! is the largest you can compute with 64-bits, so you could easily implement a macro that takes an integer N (in the range 0-20) and returns its factorial. But C's macros don't support loops, so the implementation will be hacky. Handling inputs larger than 20 would require a custom data type (or a 128-bit integer, which your compiler may support as an extension), which is possible to implement in theory, but again, it will be hacky.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Thank you guys for your answers. I think I got a good understanding of why it isn't possible to have a factorial macro. It appears that you guys understand the language. However, the question is being downvoted (probably by those who don't understand the language and just do as they're told to do), so I am probably going to have to delete the question.

Comment: @Cornstalks You were meant to be in the last comment as well, but it will only allow one per comment. Thank you as well

Comment: The question is still unclear. You have shown a factorial function in the question. What benefit do you expect by converting that function into a macro?

Comment: @user3386109 The macro expansion `FACT(20) -> 20*19*18*17*16*15*14*13*12*11*10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1`, had it been possible, would be far more clear than directly putting the expansion in the source code, and would be far more likely to compile to a compile-time constant than calling a function with a constant. The former can be done with `constprop`; The latter only with quite sophisticated IPA, analysis of the function as pure, and simulated execution of the function with that constant. It would also only work within one translation unit. Give OP some slack on this question...

Comment: Anyhow, it turns out all factorials `66!` and up are equal to `0` (modulo 2 to the power of 64), so you can make yourself a macro that checks for each case using `x == N ? val : (x == NPLUS1 ? ... : ...)` and returns the appropriate value.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist I was asking for clarification from the OP. Your interpretation of the question all very well and good. But I'm not convinced that your interpretation is correct. E.g. what if the OP intends to invoke `FACT(x)` where `x` is a variable whose value is only known at runtime. So give me some slack, and let the OP answer my question.

Comment: @user3386109 My question just applies to why this function doesn't work as a macro. It doesn't matter whether it is at runtime or not.

Comment: The function doesn't work as a macro because a macro can't *"return"* a value. Instead it must have a value. If you pass two arguments to the macro, e.g. `#define FACT(n, output)`, then it's simple enough to write a macro that computes the factorial of `n` and assigns the result to `output`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to make it a macro in the general case, but there are very few `int` values for which your factorial function is defined: it invokes undefined behavior for `N > 12` if `int` has 32 bits.

Here are many ways to take advantage of this:

```
static int const factorials[13] = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 
                                    362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600 };
#define FACT(n)  ((n) < 0 ? 1 : (n) > 12 ? INT_MAX : factorials[n])
```

Alternatively:

```
#define FACT(n) ((n) <= 1 ? 1 : \
                 (n) == 2 ? 2 : \
                 (n) == 3 ? 6 : \
                 (n) == 4 ? 24 : \
                 (n) == 5 ? 120 : \
                 (n) == 6 ? 720 : \
                 (n) == 7 ? 5040 : \
                 (n) == 8 ? 40320 : \
                 (n) == 9 ? 362880 : \
                 (n) == 10 ? 3628800 : \
                 (n) == 11 ? 39916800 : \
                 (n) == 12 ? 479001600 : INT_MAX)
```

Note that both of these evaluate `n` multiple times.

An inline function is a much better approach. Your `factorial()` might compile to a constant for a constant argument on modern optimizing compilers:

A short example using [Matt Godbolt's online compiler](https://godbolt.org/g/Qf2JJW) with clang 3.9 -O2 is very instructive:

The `factorial` function compiles to an unfathomable 235 lines of Intel SIMD code while the `int test(void) { return factorial(12); }` produces just 2 instructions:

```
test():                               # @test()
        mov     eax, 479001600
        ret
```

Even optimizing for size with `-Os` produces 49 lines of assembly code, way too large since `-O1` is much smaller at 10 lines.